# Excel formula do not update automatically

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a simple excel formula to know what is the color of the font of the cell A1

```
Function GetFontColorIndex(elrango As Range) As Integer
        Application.Volatile
       GetFontColorIndex = elrango.Cells(1, 1).Font.ColorIndex
End Function
```

In [excel-2010](/questions/tagged/excel-2010):
*File > Options > Formulas > Workbook Calculation > Automatic* is checked

In cell `A1` I have a number, and in cell `A3` I have
 `=GetFontColorIndex(A1)`

but when I change the font of cell `A1`, the formula does not update automatically on cell `A3`. I have to click `shift+F9` and then it works.

Any idea why is not showing the number of the font automatically?

Comment: From [here](http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsi.htm): `A Volatile Function in a formula in a cell makes that cell be always recalculated at each recalculation`. Changing formatting (font color) doesn't triggers recalculation. what you can do is add `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event with `ActiveSheet.Calculate`. In many cases it would solve your problem

Comment: You can also [use XLM](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/20611-info-only-get-cell-arguments.html) for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As simoco has mentioned.

If you are using your 'udf' in `Sheet1` then in the module associated with that sheet add the following:

[image]

If you just change the colour the formula does not update but as soon as you press enter or select another cell in the sheet it updates